# get url from String in android

Tags: android, url

Currently I am using the following method to get a URL from a string and insert into a TextView. It works fine, but does see  anybody any issues with this approach?

```
       public String StringURL(String args) {
            String s = args;
            String [] parts = s.split("\\s");
            String withURL = "";
            for( String item : parts ){
                if (Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(item).matches()) {
                    if (!item.startsWith("http://") && !item.startsWith("https://")){
                           item = "http://" + item;
                    }
                    withURL += "<a href=\"" + item + "\">"+ item + "</a> ";  
                }
                else {
                    withURL += item + " ";
                }
            }
            return withURL;
        }
```

In the TextView I set the returned String the following way:

```
TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(StringURL(P))); 
TextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

This method works only for SdkVersions 8+ since Patterns.WEB_URL was introduced as of SdkVersion 8.

Comment: can you post your html tag. you can use jsoup to parse and display the url

Comment: what I want to do is let user post a url in their text and then be able to make it clickable in the TextView. For instance "I found this website www.google.com"

Comment: you can use a spannable string for this purpose. does the string entered always at the end or beginning or in the middle